# Getting error in these lines

Tags: php, odbc

Warning: odbc_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid ODBC result resource in line no

error line is while row odbc fetch query

```
$query=("select * from company_master order by ccode ");
$i=1;
while($row=odbc_fetch_array($query))
{
$string.
```

Comment: wheres your `odbc_exec($query); `? RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

odbc_fetch_array expects a resource from odbc_exec(), not a string.

For example:

```
$query="select * from company_master order by ccode ";
$res = odbc_exec($conn, $query);

$results = odbc_fetch_array($res);

foreach ($results as $row) {
   //...
}
```

See the parameters section from http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-array.php

Comment: Got it Question is closed Thank you All